# mongodb find documents where all array values do NOT start with 'org:'

Tags: mongodb

Given some documents like this:

```
{
  _id: 'abc',
  extIds: ['org1:123', 'org2:xyz', 'org3:7q9']
},

{
  _id: 'def',
  extIds: ['org1:234', 'org2:tuv']
}
```

I want to match those that don't have an extId value for 'org3'.
I tried a simple regex:

```
db.ext_ids.find({
  extIds: {$regex:'^(?!org3\:)'}
})
```

But this matches all documents which have any extId value other than 'org3:...'.
Essentially, I need to evaluate the regex against all values in the array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
db.ext_ids.find({ extIds: {$not: /^org3/ }})
```

Comment: Interestingly, if you try it using the '{$regex:'^org3'}' syntax you get an error: can't use $not with $regex, use BSON regex type instead

Comment: @jckdnk111 you should try and avoid the regex operator, instead use the regex object as it says